# Update ios app with Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an iOS app in Apple Store and it needs to be updated with lots of changes. The updated one should be totally different in the code and gui.

Here are my questions.

1) The old one does not use the core data and the new one does. Is there anything I need to worry about?
2) You can consider the old and the new one as 2 different applications. Will that be any problem when a user update the app?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Nope and Nope. Just make sure you migrate existing data to Core Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding core data to your app should not cause any problems to existing users to upgrade.

Only when you upgrade an app that uses Core data, you need to perform migration.

In this case the bundle id will be the same but everything else can change without any problem.